# Having problems with if and else in list comprehensions. I need to make the list value something if the list is empty

Tags: python

I have this:

```
name_list = [x for x in list]
if not name_list:
    name_list = "n/a"
```

I want to make it in one line.

I want this:

```
name_list = ["n/a" if not x else x.text for x in list]
```

The problem I'm having if that I don't know what to put in the first x of the above code.

How do I check if the list is empty and make the value "n/a" in one line?

Comment: `name_list = [x for x in list] or "n\a"`

Comment: `name_list = [x for x in list]` -> `name_list = list(list)` or `list[:]` or `list.copy()`

Comment: you shouldnt shadow builtin functions (`list` in this case) with your variable names

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. I really appreciate it. It works! I really want to ask if this is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken here. You don't want a list comprehension. You use list comprehensions when you need to *build new lists*. That's not what you want to do here. You want to *assign a certain value to `name_list` depending on a condition*.

This can be done using Python's `or` operator. The `or` operator is short-circuited, and returns the first 'truthy' value it evaluates:

```
name_list = [x for x in list] or "n\a"
```

However, I would recommended being careful using the above code, as it can be confusing for people who aren't familiar with it. Depending on your case, it might be better to be more explicit and break the above code into two steps:

```
tmp = [x for x in list] 
name_list = tmp if tmp else "n\a"
```

Comment: You could also write `[x.text for x in my_list] if my_list else "n\a"` to get a one-liner without the `or`.

Comment: So what value would `my_list` hold prior to it's creation? In my answer, I'm assuming this is the first time the OP is creating the variable `name_list`. If so, then `name_list` couldn't be used yet because it doesn't exit.

Comment: `my_list` is the original list. I just renamed it `my_list` because naming a list `list` is bad, mkay. Also, I specified `x.text` because that's what the OP wants and because otherwise he might as well do `list(my_list)`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code snippet, if the list is empty you assign a **string** to it. Not a list. Hence you can't do it with list comprehension, as the latter always returns a **list**.

You can use other Python builtin feature to achieve that:

```
name_list = [x.text for x in list] or "n\a"
```

It will evaluate the first expression first, and if its Falsey (None, False, 0) it will use the other expression - `n\a`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) to do that like:

```
name_list = [x for x in a_list] or "n/a"
```

> [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.